# Considering Long exact sequence of cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a field $k$.

If $0 \longrightarrow F' \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow F'' \longrightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on $X$, can I move to a long exact sequence of cohomology

$... \longrightarrow H^i(X,F')\longrightarrow H^i(X,F)\longrightarrow H^i(X,F'') \longrightarrow  H^{i+1}(X,F') \longrightarrow ...$ ?

How can I justify this? Where do I find justification in Hartshorne for this?

Comment: don't need projective or over a field, and in Chapter III.

Comment: More specifically, this is part (c) of Theorem 1.1A in Chapter III. Verifying that this theorem applies amounts to 1) checking that $H^0(X,\cdot)$ is left exact (this is Exercise 1.6 from section II.1), and 2) Proposition 2.2, that the category of $\mathcal O_X$-modules has enough injective objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

It is a general fact of homological algebra, that if an abelian category $\mathcal C$ has enough injectives, then derived functors are defined, and short exact sequences in $\mathcal C$ yield long exact sequences of derived functors. See Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*, Chapter III **Theorem 1.1A**.

Now the sheaf cohomology groups $H^i(X, F)$ are defined to be the derived functors of the left-exact functor $\mathfrak{Ab}(X) \to \mathfrak{Ab}, F \mapsto \Gamma(X,F)$. This is the definition in Chapter III, **2 Cohomology of Sheaves**.